# How can we get wifi list in react-native ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I tried with react-native-wifi-reborn but i am getting
LOG  Failed to fetch Wi-Fi list [TypeError: _reactNativeWifiReborn.default.loadWifiList is not a function. (In '_reactNativeWifiReborn.default.loadWifiList()', '_reactNativeWifiReborn.default.loadWifiList' is undefined)]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can’t, because there is no public API.

From the react-native-wifi-reborn documentation, the method you are trying to use is not available for iOS.

> The following methods work only on Android
>
> loadWifiList(): Promise<Array> Returns a list of nearby
> WiFI networks.
>
> SSID: The network name. BSSID: The WiFi BSSID. capabilities: Describes
> the authentication, key management, and encryption schemes supported
> by the access point. frequency: The primary 20 MHz frequency (in MHz)
> of the channel over which the client is communicating with the access
> point. level: The detected signal level in dBm, also known as the
> RSSI. timestamp: timestamp in microseconds (since boot) when this
> result was last seen.

- Here is a GitHub issue regarding the same problem. In summary, you are unable to load the Wi-Fi list on iOS.
  https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn/issues/300
- Another thread on the topic https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/39204

> There is no Public API to casually scan for Wi-fi networks via iOS
> from inside your app.